# How to prepare a dataset with the same tags

Tags: python, machine-learning, dataset

I have the dataset such like this:

```
<tab>
    <DTPV></DTPV>
    <date></date>
    <district></district>
    <ts_info>
        <color></color>
        <t_ts></t_ts>
    </ts_info>
</tab>
    <tab>
    <DTPV></DTPV>
    <date></date>
    <district></district>
    <ts_info>
        <color></color>
        <t_ts></t_ts>
    </ts_info>
    <ts_info>
        <color></color>
        <t_ts></t_ts>
    </ts_info>
</tab>
<tab>
    <DTPV></DTPV>
    <date></date>
    <district></district>
    <ts_info>
        <color></color>
        <t_ts></t_ts>
    </ts_info>
    <ts_info>
        <color></color>
        <t_ts></t_ts>
    </ts_info>
    <ts_info>
        <color></color>
        <t_ts></t_ts>
    </ts_info>
</tab>
```

As you can see an object can have the same tag in multiple instances (<ts_info>).

In the model, I would like to use the tag "color", but in the first case it is one, in the second - two, in the third - three. Also, I can't guarantee that the maximum number of tags "ts_info" is three.

So, what should i do with this tag to prepare the dataset?

Any advice is welcome!

Comment: Treat this attribute as a list and when you want to train the model do one-hot encoding

Answer (score 0):

```python
from xmljson import badgerfish as bf
from xml.etree.ElementTree import fromstring
import json

xml = """
<root>
<tab>
    <DTPV>1</DTPV>
    <date>1</date>
    <district>1</district>
    <ts_info>
        <color>11</color>
        <t_ts>11</t_ts>
    </ts_info>
</tab>
    <tab>
    <DTPV>2</DTPV>
    <date>2</date>
    <district>2</district>
    <ts_info>
        <color>22</color>
        <t_ts>22</t_ts>
    </ts_info>
    <ts_info>
        <color>222</color>
        <t_ts>222</t_ts>
    </ts_info>
</tab>
<tab>
    <DTPV>3</DTPV>
    <date>3</date>
    <district>3</district>
    <ts_info>
        <color>33</color>
        <t_ts>33</t_ts>
    </ts_info>
    <ts_info>
        <color>333</color>
        <t_ts>333</t_ts>
    </ts_info>
    <ts_info>
        <color>3333</color>
        <t_ts>3333</t_ts>
    </ts_info>
</tab>
</root>
"""

b = bf.data(fromstring(xml))
print(json.dumps(b))
```

output: {"root": {"tab": [{"DTPV": {"$": 1}, "date": {"$": 1}, "district": {"$": 1}, "ts_info": {"color": {"$": 11}, "t_ts": {"$": 11}}}, {"DTPV": {"$": 2}, "date": {"$": 2}, "district": {"$": 2}, "ts_info": [{"color": {"$": 22}, "t_ts": {"$": 22}}, {"color": {"$": 222}, "t_ts": {"$": 222}}]}, {"DTPV": {"$": 3}, "date": {"$": 3}, "district": {"$": 3}, "ts_info": [{"color": {"$": 33}, "t_ts": {"$": 33}}, {"color": {"$": 333}, "t_ts": {"$": 333}}, {"color": {"$": 3333}, "t_ts": {"$": 3333}}]}]}}

continue to work as with a normal json